Would superhuman elites allow for more liberal governance?
Suppose, if you will, that the aristocracy of my fictional pre-Christian European nation is entirely composed of superhumans. The source of their powers lies in their blood, and can only be inherited by birth - and not just normal birth, but birth to a father and mother from this elite class.
They are significantly more powerful than their mundane subjects. A rebellion, even if the rebels outnumber the aristocrats a million to one and with the best weapons available, would not just fail- it would fail to even remotely threaten the aristocrats. For all practical purposes, no force normal people can bring to bear can harm or impede their aristocrats.
This is common knowledge, and both classes know this. Now to the meat of the question. Their ruler is under the belief that since their monopoly on force is unquestionable, it would be quite safe to rule in a more liberal manner. Smaller armies, less policing, some freedom of speech and religion and lenient taxation are some of the policies being suggested. Just to be clear, foreign attacks are not a serious threat either.
Will this policy manage to maintain the peace? Or could it lead to anarchy as the elites (just about a couple thousand people ruling a population of just under 80 Million people) fail to maintain control? And even if they do fail, would it really even be a problem?
Naturally, we shall compare the performance of these policies to whether they match up to similarly sized polities in "our" world. To put it this way, would this country be more or less dysfunctional than "our" empires?

Not quite a full answer, but just keep in mind what happens to real-world countries when the elite has “powers” like economic/political asymmetry, better tech and living, etc. What you’ve done is given the elite actual powers, not just having more [insert luxury/commodity here] than the others. Expect very large class discrimination and imbalance.

I fail to see where the distinction aristocracy/subjects differs from the Classical Athenian citizen/slaves, the Roman patricians/plebs, the MA freemen/serfs, etc. As long as the elite remains in power, you may cushion their internal strifes with however much liberalism as you please.

Their ruler is under the belief that since their monopoly on force is unquestionable, it would be quite safe to rule in a more liberal manner. The entire history of humanity proves this to be wrong. Keep in mind that humanity invented the phrase, "absolute power corrupts absolutely." The ancient Egyptians, Romans, Greeks (to name a few) had unquestioned power and liberalism never made it to the surfs, peons or slaves. However, you're asking this question as if there were an absolute, definitive answer. In reality, you will have the outcome you want if you write it that way.

I say the ultimate rule of governing is the rule of power, whoever has more power is the ruler. So, superhumans would just treat normal humans as slaves or worse, while they would divide influence between them somehow. In fact you're asking for whether a typical xianxia would allow at least a controlled monarchy upon the controlled lands and non-ascending populace; and as such the answer is a definite no, because of the usual mindset of the genre. With medieval Europe pulled into a xianxia, the answer is likely the same.

Could the commoners somehow help an aristocrat in an aristocrat infight? My idea is that the commoners find infights between the aristocrats, and then they offer their until-death service to the weaker site. Hope is that by helping the weaker to win, maybe they will be friendlier to them as their previous rulers. They also could make themselves an important resource, and they also could get a revenge on their enslavers. Winning over some aristocrat, by helping a weaker branch. and then skinning them and then letting them eat by its mates, that would be clearly an eternal remembrance...

Parallel: poisonous snakes have no way to exterminate the humanity. But, if I could talk with such a snake, I could let him kill practically anyone.

With a monopoly on force, why should the elites even care what the commoners do? As long as the taxes are paid, the commoners can do whatever they want including having their own style of religion, policing, and order.

I believe knowing what makes these humans superhuman is important here as well. Are they feared for their powers? Are they super-intelligent? More importantly, do these powers have any bearing on their ability to guide others? Are they omniscient? Governing takes manpower, among other things, no matter how strong (for example) one is.

@Joachim I think the question indirectly suggests a genetical source, or a source working as if it would be genetical (note the werewolves in the white wolf systems, if you did not hear about it, google for: "werewolf the apocalypse").

Somewhat related question: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/234627/how-could-peasants-protest-against-superhuman-kings

We basically have that scenario play out in the real world. Its called Dhubai. The aristocrats think they are super-human- and they are, there super-power is money. But a system not afflicted with problems, does not solve them in a reasonable and efficient way for non-superhumans. Thats how you get poop-trucks instead of canalisation. Let the servs handle it.. no need for improvement.

We've added a chatroom to hopefully help work on some questions that don't fit the usual model particularly well, if you want some further input head over to Story Tellers Corner with your question and we'll see if we can help.

I don't remember of any concept of "liberal" government in pre-Christian Europe: everywhere there was always a clear and sharp distinction between "us" and "them". "Us" being either citizen/fellow tribe members, aristocrats, senators, and "them" being anyone else, with way less rights and protection, not much different than objects at free disposal of "us".
If you aim to stay within the modus governandi of those times, there is no chance that any ruler will come out with a concept remotely similar to what we call today a liberal government. It's like expecting that you start treating the tools in your toolbox more magnanimously and equally just because you are sure that they can never revolt against you.

Hmm and now I'm thinking of some weird animation film of tools rising up against their oppressors or to go on an exodus to a land where they can choose their own labour. Tool Story

This is why we fear A.I. we - as a species - are utterly crap at treating other "people" with respect.

In fact, to make a point, the first time the magnanimously granted liberalism got in the way of a goal of leadership that would be the beginning of the end of liberalism. Liberalism is a luxury enjoyed by a free society where the governed and the government are more-or-less balanced in power and usually the consequence of using that balance to better protect one or more social minorities. But when a minority holds most of the power, only the trappings of liberalism can be expected as it becomes a tool to manage the masses.

No.
Your rulers would not just need to be safe from attack from commoners, they need to be able to coerce them to pay taxes, etc. Otherwise they are not rulers, they are a separate and unconnected class.
One could try to imagine a situation where the rulers are a bit like the gods of the Greek or Roman pantheon, able to do whatever they want to mere 'mortals.' But if they want to extract wealth, they need a bureaucracy, or perhaps priests to translate the surplus of millions of farmers into a few mansions, a few imported silk gowns, the very best food and drink. The tax collectors have to take the produce of the farmers to pay specialist artisans. These specialists then consume the ordinary food and produce luxury items. The bureaucracy is staffed with 'mortals' who are vulnerable to attack if they overdo their depredations. Caught between a rock and a hard place -- if they do not deliver for the 'pantheon,' they are more vulnerable because they are visible to the rulers.

You are not asking the right question
This is a form of Frame Challenge - with a monopoly on power- your system could easily turn into China or North Korea.
However, let's assume that the desire is to have a libertarian system. What is required is belief.
I am going to use Taxes as an example.
People often argue about Taxes being too high or not high enough, but both of these are surface level complaints:
The person complaining that Taxes are too high is paying money and not seeing any discernable return for their taxes
The person complaining that Taxes are not high enough (although curiously, only for people richer than they are...) is seeing needs not being met due to insufficient public funding.
The root cause in both scenarios is not seeing the purported benefit of the Taxes being paid.
If I am being taxed at an increased rate, yet my roads are full of potholes, the wait time for Doctors has doubled and the teachers are overworked and not providing the quality of education I pay for - then I'm not going to be happy with the tax rate.
Whereas, if I'm Taxed at the same rate, but the roads are in good order, wait times are reasonable etc. Then I'm more inclined to accept the tax rate.
Now, apply that same logic to all areas: if I can do all the things I need or want to do, without excessive government interference - then I'm less likely to complain.
Conversely, when I choose to interact with the government, it should be efficient and relatively painless.
The individual needs to believe that their rights are honored, their Taxes are spent wisely, that the courts are just, the police are prudent etc.
Once you have that, the how is irrelevant.

Depends
Whether they can keep the peace is more about the interpersonal relationships between the elites.
Throughout history we can see many elites that were pretty certain about their position. Though some were buddies, others were hunting the other person their small folk. They did this for enjoyment, or to bring an economic blow to the other, or just to send a message. Elites from the same country could clash between themselves, trying to better themselves in position, land or riches.
Being untouchable by your small folk does not mean there is no conflict. It can certainly lead to a long upheld liberal rule. It can just as well be petty squabbles between the elites where the small folk can be harmed. You got to do something if you covet the wife of another, or like the gold mine, or just one of the very talented small folk.
That means it is more a result of how you write the elites. The small folk are easily cowed if they would break the peace of your liberal law. The elites are the only true source of friction, if they decide to act badly on anything that happens.

Well, they are reasonably cohesive under their patriarch, who's the oldest and strongest of the lot. I suppose things will change once he dies.

You can't just answer this as yes or no.
Historically, any time we're put in a position where one side has unquestioned superiority, the superior ones decide that the inferior ones are less than human. The only way we avoid this today is by declaring by fiat that everyone of our species is created equal. Even that is an uphill battle.
In your situation, you would get one set of rules for the super-beings and another for the plebeian. In the real world, this situation automatically comes into being even in cases where the superiority is presumed. If it were empirical, then the division would be a given.
"Liberal" in this perspective probably means letting the plebes do their own governing.
The supers would likely have carte blanche on how they treat the plebes, but you'd have ownership rights, deciding who gets to use the manpower generated by plebes in a geographic area, who you have to pay reparations to if you kill their plebes, etc. Basically like cattle or natural resources.

If your ruling class is too small for their territory, say a king, his family and a few ducal families, it would probably not change much, because even with Superman or Super Saiyan level of powers, the rulers simply don't have the time to micro-manage the commoners themselves and also, probably, no desire to do it (who wants to dirty their fine clothes supervising the peons when they could enjoy a good wine on the terrace of their summer villa instead?).
They would rely on commisioners taken from the common people, and it is those agents of the crown who would be regularly in contact with the crowds, and subject to their revolts. Historically revolts were rarely directed at the head of state, but instead went after their proxies.
It only makes sense: the king is far in his castle with a small army of guards and can easily give himself a positive image among the commoners. The abusive tax collector or cop, on the other hand, is right here in front the people he abuses, and he is not as well protected. Even in modern societies rioters are seldom going for the presidential palace, instead focusing on symbols of power in their area, like a police station or just shops.
Also, commoner on commoner crime would not change, and if normal people far outnumber the superhumans it would have to be handled by commoner sheriffs and judges, who would in turn become as many targets of revolt.

Important question: is the Super Aristocracy up for doing "public works"? Or are they fine just sitting on their super-asses all day doing nothing of importance?
The reason Im asking is that if the Aristocrats are truly Supermen, they could easily prop-up the economy to the point at which liberalism and good welfare are a possibility. The sole fact that the Super Prince is strong enough to lift a mountain is a deterrent from rebellion. But if the Super Prince ACTUALLY lifted some heavy rocks to open mines, carve tunnels, channels and roads, if he cut down whole forests with his laser beams, towed giant merchant ships at motorboat speeds etc etc, he could vastly increase the standards of living for his subjects. A hour or two of "public works" from a mountain-busting supersonic being would be worth more than a year of labor of all the peons combined.
The main reason pre-modern societies suffered, was that there was simply not enough free energy to go around, as calories, fuel, and means to extract resources, so it bread conflict and enforced sacrifices. An indestructible Superman is a one man nuclear powerplant, that can improve the energy output of his kingdom by an order of magnitude.
So, assuming the Super-Aristocrats WANT to have a nice, liberal, welfare kingdom and are willing to put in some work (even a little bit, just for fun, treating his kingdom like a Minecraft game and his peons as beloved pets) it would be possible.

They have no interest in doing any productive work. The only work they will do is fighting or "intellectual" works. And when I said "liberal", I meant it in the classical sense.

@Thales, then it is hopeless, because the system itself will not be rich enough to make liberalism plausible, and not collapse. It does not matter if the Aristocrats are Supers or not, if the life below them is crude feudalism by technical necessity.

"Will this policy manage to maintain the peace?"
No.  A real society is more complex than just a united ruling class and a united commoner class.  There will still be intra-class conflict.  Surely there are different factions within the commoners and within the rulers.
You've laid out a pretty good reason for why there would not be much incentive for the commoners to rebel against the elites in general; but what's stopping one faction of elites from trying to turn the commoners against another faction of elites?  Violent civil unrest still seems possible to me.

Because there's not much of a point in it. The commoners are simply not a concern for any conflict.

@Thales Unless the elites are relatively evenly matched, in which case the commoners can break the tie.  Who has better odds of winning; 50 super soldiers, or 50 super soldiers with 10,000 commoner auxiliaries?

@Thales if the commoners are irrelevant in all ways then the aristocracy wouldn't interact with them in any organised way at all, the aristocracy would pretty much ignore them the way we ignore... butterflies, or sparrows, or earthworms.  The commoners must provide something they need that they must rule them to obtain.  Which means that if the commoners provide food/taxes/intelligence preferentially to a particular subset of the aristocracy then that subset will have an advantage.

@KerrAvon2055 They do provide taxes, because gods forbid the aristocrats do any real work. But taxes are derived from the government's monopoly on force, so it's not like they can choose not to pay them.

@Thales What's stopping a faction of the elites from getting people to dodge some of those taxes?  In real life taxes don't go into one big pool, different tax programs fund different budget items.  Like in the US your local highschool is funded by a local tax, not your Federal income tax.  What's stopping a faction of elites from getting commoners to dodge the ones that fund their enemies?  Alternatively, what's stopping a faction of elites from seeking extra income?  Either by commoner donations or by force/extortion?

@Why would they do so? And I suppose the answer would be nothing. If they are in a position to remove taxation, they are free to do so. And if they wish to steal more money, then all that can stop them is the King or other elites ganging up on them.

@Thales : "The commoners are simply not a concern for any conflict" - this is incorrect. If neighboring factions of superhumans have a war, what is easier? To attack the superhumans on the opposite side, or to attack their villages to deny the other faction the resources? This is very similar to many medieval and early modern conflicts. Heavily armored knights could easily defeat masses of poorly equipped peasants, so in many wars it was far less risky to defeat the opponent by looting their villages and denying them resources, than risk a pitched battle against their military.

@Thales "then all that can stop them is the King or other elites ganging up on them."  This is that internal conflict I'm talking about.

The aristocratic guys would fight each other. And that would be a way, where even a commoner could get a revenge on an aristocratic.
We are actually quite liberal rulers of the pigs. Or of the horses. We know, what do they like and what not, and we do not allow the herd to harm our property - for example, we do not close together two male horses not knowing each other. Beside that, on their encircled area, the horses are free to decide, where do they graze, with whom do they have sex (if we allow a male horse into there) and so on.
However, we, humans have a habit to regularly kill each other in various wars. We also have our internal hierarchy - particularly the guys, whose daily job is to shoveling the excrement of the horses every day, are not really top in it. We suppress each other in this hierarchy, and only the Workplace SE can say, what type of sophisticated and totally unneeded lowries are we ready to happily do, in order to harm each other in this hierarchy.
While all of us, without an exception, enjoys a much higher position as the team leader horse in the stall.
There would be liberalism, but among the aristocrats, there would be also suppressed guys, and they had infights. It depends on the details, how would affect our chances, if at least a weak part of the aristocrats would side with us, or we would side with them.

Classical Athens was a splendid democracy, provided one was an Athenian citizen. To be an Athenian citizen, one had to be a man born of an Athenian father and an Athenian mother.
Rome was never a particularly democratic republic, but, unlike Athens, Rome made it very clear from the very beginning that anybody could become a Roman. Rome was the first state in the entire history to realize that citizenship and ethnicity were two different things, and one did not have to depend on the other. The Romans even gave Roman citizenship to manumitted slaves! Shocking!
Compare and contrast the fate of Athens with the fate of Rome.

I don't see what that has to do with my question.

You need to educate yourself about Sumerians, Akkadians, Ancient Persians (the first and the second empire - the latter founded by Cyrus the first in 6th century BC) 4,000 years of Before Christ Chinese kingdoms and empires, and ofcourse Pharoah ruled Egypt. Slavery was never that widespread, dependent on or brutal as was in Athens and Roman republic and empire. Also, how did you get 93k+ points here without ability to understand the question asked speak volumes about this site.
